# Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord

Tags: android, android-activity, timeout

When I start my main activity I will check if the preferences are setted. If not I will start the preferences activity. On android 1.6 all right, but from the next versions I'm taking this timeout for HistoryRecord:

**08-19 22:21:18.705: WARN/ActivityManager(55): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{4508b3f0 com.cartrafficlive/.view.ShowMap}
**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.show_map);

loadPreferences();

if (depAdd.equals("") || arrAdd.equals(""))
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Preferences.class));

loadMap();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably I’m getting this message because my emulator is too slow and the app is taking too much time to show the activity.